# Android studio reformat code multiple formatting issue

Tags: android, android-studio, coding-style

I'm encountering problem with Android studio formatting and the use case is:

Using Android studio 1.5.1 with my custom code style defined. Right click on a package and "Reformat code...", Check only on "Include subdirectories" and click Run. It gives me one-line changes in three classes. After that, if I repeat the same procedure, I get more changes in these three classes. After that, if I repeat the same procedure, I get even more formatting changes (using Github for Windows to see the changes).

How is that possible? Is someone experiencing the same problem?